# Formatar linha com itextsharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Como posso construir uma linha com diferentes formatações no itextsharp?

Tentei dessa forma:

```
Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(Texto, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, tamanho, estilo));
doc.Add(paragrafo);
```

Mas a cada "add" ele joga em uma linha nova e nao a frente da anterior.

Se alguem puder me ajudar, desde ja obrigado.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "à frente da anterior" ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo acredito que ele esteja falando de continuar na mesma linha do paragrafo adicionado anteriormente.

Comment: Isso é um comportamento padrão, o certo seria fazer um StringBuilder e gerar sua propriedade texto antes de passar o paragrafo e adicionar ele.

Comment: @MagnoCosta Inclua o código inteiro do método.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo , isso mesmo, continuar na mesma linha.
O código basicamente isso, posso incluir a rotina inteira, mas vai adicionar apenas a "public void e }" ao final.

Comment: @Paz, entao, no momento é feito assim mesmo, crio um stringbuilder, gero a linha  e mando pro paragrafo, porém isso nao me permite trabalhar os formatos, por exemplo: "CLIENTE: ABC" sendo "CLIENTE" em negrito e ABC nao.. entende?

Comment: Onde está o seu string builder? você está apresentando a parte errada do código não é aí onde está seu problema

Comment: @LeandroAngelo abaixo esta o codigo mais completo.

Answer (score 1):

Como esta:

```
public void impF(ref StringBuilder ret, int pos, string Texto, bool pulaLinha, float fs = 7.0F, int estilo = 0)
{
    if (pulaLinha)
    {
        string x = ret + l(Texto, " ", pos - linha.Length) + "\r\n";
        ret.Clear();
        linha = "";
        Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(x, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, fs, estilo));
        doc.Add(paragrafo);
    }
    else
    {
        //paragrafo.Add(l(Texto, " ", pos - linha.Length) + "\r\n");
        ret.Append(l(Texto, " ", pos - linha.Length));
        linha += l(Texto, " ", pos - linha.Length);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma ele monta a linha no stringbuilder e qdo solicitado adiciona ao paragrafo.

Gostaria de adicionar ao paragrafo cada texto independente cada um com seu estilo (negrito, italico, tamanho etc)

Seria algo assim:

```
public void impF(ref StringBuilder ret, int pos, string Texto, bool pulaLinha, float fs = 7.0F, int estilo = 0)
{
    Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph(Texto, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, fs, estilo));
    doc.Add(paragrafo);
    if (pulaLinha)
    {
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("\r\n"));
    }
}
```

Essa rotina é chamada assim:

```
 GeraRelatorio.impF(ref texto, 01, "Operação: " + row["cdescropera"].ToString(), true);
```

Esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém o estilo só pode ser aplicado a linha inteira.

Answer (score 1):

```
Phrase texto_1= new Phrase("cliente: ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.GRAY)); 

Phrase texto_2 = new Phrase(ViewBag.Nome + " "+ ViewBag.Sobrenome, new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12f, Font.NORMAL));


Paragraph texto_2_formatacoes= new Paragraph{texto_1, texto_2 };

doc.add(texto_2_formatacoes)
```

os 2 textos tem de ser `Phrase`. Se for `Paragraph` não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criar várias Phrase com configurações diferentes e adicionar ao parágrafo

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragrah();

Phrase phrase1 = new Phrase("Texto negrito",
           BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVEDICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, 
           BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED));

Phrase phrase2 = new Phrase("Texto itálico",
           BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVEDICA_ITALIC, BaseFont.CP1252, 
           BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED));

 paragraph.Add(phrase1);
 paragraph.Add(phrase2);
```

Outra coisa que pode ser feito é utilizar vários ContentByte na mesma linha ao invés de usar Paragraph.
A desvantagem é que o ContentByte não quebra linha, o desafio seria identificar onde eles devem iniciar (ao final do anterior).
Caso o texto anterior não varie, como por exemplo uma label, vai funcionar bem, se forem textos variados não vai funcionar bem.